# How to update logged in user details in database spring boot , Jpa Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to update details for currently logged in user to my local database:

```
@PostMapping("/Balnce_add")
public String GoesUp(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails currentuser) throws IOException {
    int x=currentuser.getBalance() +10;
    currentuser.setBalance(x);
    repo.save(logindata);
    System.out.println("cool ==> "+currentuser.setBalance(x));
    return "user";
    
}
```

This is my form code to update:

```
<form action="" th:action="@{Balnce_add}" method="post">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
     </form>
```

But my current code is not updating the value for the logged in user instead it's making a new record with balance only.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot make a comment I will make an answer. Why are you saving `logindata` to the repo and not the user object itself? Also when you are updating an existing object, you should either use PATCH or PUT because you are updating a user with its new balance.

Read more about PATCH/PUT and other HTTP request types: [What’s the Difference between PUT vs PATCH?](https://rapidapi.com/blog/put-vs-patch/)